# why is postgresql considering this subquery column-name not fully qualified and ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, ambiguity

```
  Select distinct A.col1, B.col2, col3
   from A inner join B on A.id = B.id
   and B.id in 

       (select distinct col2 from B where ..... )
```

PostgreSQL's plpgsql parser does not like the unqualified "col2" in the parenthetic subquery.  Since there's only one table mentioned in the subquery, isn't the parser manufacturing an ambiguity where there is none?

Comment: Maybe you can add the tables definition as well, so we can put the query into a context? Only with this piece of code, I don't see any problem and my tests confirm there is no issue. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3c1a4/1

Comment: The subselect should just work. Please add the **verbatim error message**, your **version of PostgreSQL** table definitions and the full query (or full plpgsql function definition). There has to be some kind of misunderstanding here. You mention plpgsql .. could be a naming conflict with function parameters.

Comment: What Erwin is really asking for a called a "reproduceable test case"  i.e. you should give US the folks trying to help everything we need to try and reproduce your problem.  If you give us a set of create table and insert statements and an exact select query that causes this error, we can do a LOT more to help.  as it is we're like blind men describing an elephant.  Five guesses and none of them complete. Also in trying to create a test case you often see the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SQL query like you display would just work.

Since you mention **plpgsql**, my shot in the dark is that you are only showing fragments from what is actually a plpgsql function and you run into naming conflicts with function parameters, which are visible *anywhere* in the function body (except dynamic SQL).

Comment: But it wasn't function parameter conflict.  I am inserting several times into a temporary table, and the column name is referenced in multiple places in the function, and not always from the same table. The function is very long and the table-defs are quite large, so I won't post them.

Answer (score 2):

No. Outer query columns are available in the subquery too, otherwise you couldn't bind the inner and outer queries together. It's an easy thing to forget and can catch you out if you're not expecting it.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. In what context would a subquery that is `SELECT`ing only `FROM B` without `JOIN`ing on another table need to refer to a column from some other table? In fact, what would that even mean and in what context would it be legal syntax? Substituting `SELECT DISTINCT A.col2 FROM B` for `SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM B` here seems meaningless and I would expect it to be a syntax error; I think that's what the asker was getting at.

Comment: @Richard Huxton: If the column-name in question were on the right side of a comparison in the where-clause of the subquery, perhaps.  But when the column-name flagged by the parser as ambiguous precedes the from-clause `select distinct col2 from B` and there is only one table mentioned in the from-clause, there's no ambiguity.

Comment: You might not think there is ambiguity, but both col2 are visible. You can argue that the standards should specify that the inner column should be preferred, but I don't believe it does.

Comment: @Richard Huxton: but I'm not arguing that the subquery column should be preferred when there is an ambiguity but that when the column-name precedes the from-clause, there is no ambiguity at least with that specific reference. Fully qualifying the col-name solves the problem, of course, so it's not a biggie.

Comment: While columns from the outer query are visible, a column that isn't table-qualified defaults to tables from the inner query. So this answer cannot explain the problem.